# Problems executing REG ADD inside a FOR loop in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I've created a batch file containing a line like this:

`REG ADD "HKCR\VLC.%%G\shell\folder1\folder2" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\\program.exe\" \"%%1\"" /f`

and it works correctly, if I want to change multiple lines using a for loop I get this error with the same statement:

```
\Program\program.exe\" \"%1\"" non atteso.
```

I've tried using a path without spaces in it and it works correctly. 
How can I make it work with a path with spaces?

Comment: You should show the code of your loop

Comment: I've noticed that the problem aren't the spaces, but the ")" that I think is interpreted as the end of the loop. There's an escape character to avoid this problem?

Comment: Yes the `^` caret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you figured out already, it's a problem with the closing parenthesis of `(x86)`.
Normally this would be no problem inside quotes, but as you also have quotes in your registry value, they break the batch escaping.

Instead of hard coded escaping with a caret you could also use delayed expansion here.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\program.exe" "%%1""
set "value=!value:"=\"!"
for %%a in (dummy) do (
    REG ADD "HKCR\VLC.%%G\shell\folder1\folder2" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "!value!" /f
)
```

Comment: I've tried a batch script with your code but the final output is this:         `(REG ADD "HKCR\VLC.%G\shell\folder1\folder2" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "!value!" /f )` so it doesn't give errors but the `!value!` content is not read. I've also tried writing (x86^) like this but it doesn't work either

Comment: Do you mean the debug output of the cmd.exe? There you never see expanded values for delayed expansion. You should check the results with regedit

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so stuck looking at the command output that I've never let the script write the windows registry...